# '1' is incompatible with attribute textSize (attr) dimension

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I can not change my code before this problem. But, it is occured when I build my project. I can not solve and understand what it is? Could you help me, please? I use Android Studio 3.2.1

```
Output:  
C:\Users\Lenovo\AndroidStudioProjects\Paintmet\app\src\main\res\drawable- 
v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:7: error: '1' is incompatible with attribute 
textSize (attr) dimension.

v21\ic_launcher_background.xml:10: error: '0.8' is incompatible with 
attribute textSize (attr) dimension.
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a unit, such as `sp`, `dp` or `px`.

The recommendation is to use `sp` for text, as this will scale with the system font size and the system density. `1` and `0.8` will be tiny, though. You'll want at least `14sp`.

```
android:textSize="18sp"
```

Comment: I can't change my ic_launcher_background.xml files. There are a lot of same problems on those files.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the answer. The answer is delete to drawable folder in res folder. And then copy to other project drawable folder to there.